# Invalid arguments in foreach() function

Tags: php, arrays

[This is the error which i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVPZl.png)
I am trying to fetch an array in codeignitor but it is giving me this error:

```
   <?php
        foreach($name as $object)
        {
            echo $object->name . '<br/>';
        }

    ?>
```

And my Controller  code is

```
 public function index()
{
    $this->home();
}
public function home()
{
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    $data['title'] ='First MVC tutorial';
    $data['page_header'] ='Intro to  MVC';
    $data['name'] = $this->model_users->getNames();
    $data['users'] = $this->model_users->getUsers();

    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);

}
```

This is the model

class Model_users extends CI_Model  {

```
    function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    function getNames()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT name from users');


        if($query->num_rows>0){


            return $query ->result();
        }
        else{

            return NULL;
        }
    }

        function getUsers()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from users');


        if($query->num_rows>0){


            return $query->result();
        }
        else{

            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

So can anyone help me solve this error??
As i am new to new to codeignitor

Thanks in advance.

[This is the screenshot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNt4e.png)

Comment: "it is giving me this error:" - what error? That's just some code. Please edit your question to include the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any rows in your `users` table?
It seems that your model returns null, and foreach expects an Array as it's array_expression var. Could be an empty array as well.
So you might wan't to change the

```
return NULL;
```

to

```
return [];
```

in your model and that should at least prevent the error.

p.s.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I have attached more details in the question

Comment: `foreach($name as $object)` - that's the line that is throwing the error in the screenshot. The $name variable is NULL. If you implement the change in my previous answer it should work fine.

Comment: i implemented that but then it is printing blank screen. No error is shown. I wanted the desired output

Comment: That's because you don't have anything in your `users` table. Insert a record there and I bet it will come up on the page.

Comment: See above i have sent the screenshot of my table with records